# Make a division of a stat/number from another stat/number in bash

Tags: bash, division

I have a simply question but I'm not this able with bash, I'm using a command line to get the number of queries and cached queries my Pi-Hole makes to Unbound (recursive DNS) and I want to display the cached queries as % of total queries, here're the lines to get the total queries:

```
sudo unbound-control stats_noreset | awk -F '=' '/total.num.queries/ {print $NF}'
```

this gives me for example `1500` and I want to divide this number with this line:

```
sudo unbound-control stats_noreset | awk -F '=' '/total.num.cachehits/ {print $NF}'
```

this give me for example `500` and I want to display it as:

```
500 33.3%
```

with one line code only, not with variables.

Thanks a lot! I was trying for days.

Edit: as asked, the full output of sudo unbound-control stats_noreset is:

```
sudo unbound-control stats_noreset
thread0.num.queries=1294
thread0.num.queries_ip_ratelimited=0
thread0.num.cachehits=327
thread0.num.cachemiss=967
thread0.num.prefetch=134
thread0.num.zero_ttl=0
thread0.num.recursivereplies=967
thread0.requestlist.avg=0.334242
thread0.requestlist.max=9
thread0.requestlist.overwritten=0
thread0.requestlist.exceeded=0
thread0.requestlist.current.all=0
thread0.requestlist.current.user=0
thread0.recursion.time.avg=0.080698
thread0.recursion.time.median=0.0325689
thread0.tcpusage=0
thread1.num.queries=1309
thread1.num.queries_ip_ratelimited=0
thread1.num.cachehits=342
thread1.num.cachemiss=967
thread1.num.prefetch=132
thread1.num.zero_ttl=0
thread1.num.recursivereplies=967
thread1.requestlist.avg=0.374886
thread1.requestlist.max=9
thread1.requestlist.overwritten=0
thread1.requestlist.exceeded=0
thread1.requestlist.current.all=0
thread1.requestlist.current.user=0
thread1.recursion.time.avg=0.075309
thread1.recursion.time.median=0.0322503
thread1.tcpusage=0
thread2.num.queries=1338
thread2.num.queries_ip_ratelimited=0
thread2.num.cachehits=336
thread2.num.cachemiss=1002
thread2.num.prefetch=156
thread2.num.zero_ttl=0
thread2.num.recursivereplies=1002
thread2.requestlist.avg=0.360104
thread2.requestlist.max=9
thread2.requestlist.overwritten=0
thread2.requestlist.exceeded=0
thread2.requestlist.current.all=0
thread2.requestlist.current.user=0
thread2.recursion.time.avg=0.073632
thread2.recursion.time.median=0.031425
thread2.tcpusage=0
thread3.num.queries=1258
thread3.num.queries_ip_ratelimited=0
thread3.num.cachehits=339
thread3.num.cachemiss=919
thread3.num.prefetch=127
thread3.num.zero_ttl=0
thread3.num.recursivereplies=919
thread3.requestlist.avg=0.315488
thread3.requestlist.max=9
thread3.requestlist.overwritten=0
thread3.requestlist.exceeded=0
thread3.requestlist.current.all=0
thread3.requestlist.current.user=0
thread3.recursion.time.avg=0.073834
thread3.recursion.time.median=0.0308651
thread3.tcpusage=0
total.num.queries=5199
total.num.queries_ip_ratelimited=0
total.num.cachehits=1344
total.num.cachemiss=3855
total.num.prefetch=549
total.num.zero_ttl=0
total.num.recursivereplies=3855
total.requestlist.avg=0.34673
total.requestlist.max=9
total.requestlist.overwritten=0
total.requestlist.exceeded=0
total.requestlist.current.all=0
total.requestlist.current.user=0
total.recursion.time.avg=0.075873
total.recursion.time.median=0.0317773
total.tcpusage=0
time.now=1613041718.040611
time.up=14305.501526
time.elapsed=14305.501526
```

thread0,1,etc..are the cores but my interest is only the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you say without variables, you mean without variables *in the shell*.

With this in mind, you can use awk variables to store the intermediate result:

```sh
sudo unbound-control stats_noreset | awk -F '=' '$1 == "total.num.queries" {queries=$NF} $1 == "total.num.cachehits" {hits=$NF}END{print hits, hits/queries*100"%"}'
```

or in a more readable multi-line format:

```sh
sudo unbound-control stats_noreset | 
   awk -F '=' '$1 == "total.num.queries" { queries = $NF }
               $1 == "total.num.cachehits" { hits = $NF }
               END { print hits, hits / queries * 100 "%" }'
```

The output is:

```
1344 25.8511%
```

If you need only a single decimal place in the output, you can use `printf`, like

```
END { printf "%d %.1f%%\n", hits, hits / queries * 100 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't work, as output I get: **1239 inf%**. That is the correct number of queries but instead the number of percent i get only a "inf" text.

Comment: @giuliomagnifico: That means that the denominator has a zero value, try printing the value of `queries` variable to see why it doesn't get the correct value. Also edit your question to include the output of `sudo unbound-control stats_noreset` command, so that we don't rely on guesswork.

Comment: And that's the trouble for what I asked: I want to display to output as a division not as an absolute percent, but the percent should be the number of total queries.

Comment: I edited the question with the full output but I don't understand what you mean for "try printing the value of queries".

Comment: @giuliomagnifico: See the edit on the answer, the problem is that the first regex matched both `total.num.queries=5199` and 
`total.num.queries_ip_ratelimited=0` lines, so you got a zero value. The new version should be more robust with the string comparison.

Comment: Great thanks a lot, this works! Just one final question if possibile: a single decimal before the **%** with printf but corrected for your last edit.  Thanks again

Comment: Got it alone in my script by inserting two digit before the **%**         ` "Cached:" "$(sudo unbound-control stats_noreset | awk -F '=' '$1 == "total.num.queries" {queries=$NF} $1 == "total.num.cachehits" {hits=$NF}END{printf "%d, %.1f\n", hits, hits/queries*100"%"}')% " `

Comment: @giuliomagnifico: Good point, edited, that seems more portable, on my system I have GNU awk and it works with single `%`, but double `%%` is better.